# Meaning of divergent limit?

Tags: limits, terminology

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} {\frac{1}{\sin x}}$$

- What is its value?
- What is the meaning of limit diverges?
- Can I say here that the limit does not exist?

Comment: that it doesn't converge ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not converge to any value, it diverges by oscillation.
1/sin(x)=csc(x) and the csc keeps cyclically jumping from -inf -> -1 -> -inf -> inf -> 1 -> inf -> -inf ->...... and never converges to anything. This is like asking what is the limit of the sequence 1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1..... as the index tends to infinity.

Comment: and how can i find that it diverge using limits??

Comment: can i say here that limit DNE

Comment: Limit(n->inf) 2 Pi n+Pi/2=1

Comment: Limit(n->inf) 2 Pi n-Pi/2=-1

Comment: Those are two different sequence limits obtained by using different paths to infinity.

Comment: can i take Limit(n->inf) 2 Pi n+Pi= infinity.. does that show limit diverge

Comment: That does not really make sense, you are taking the limit of the sequence +-inf,+-inf,+-inf,+-inf,+-inf,+-inf,+-inf,+-inf,+-inf,+-inf,.....

Comment: does every non converging limit diverge

Comment: Since all elements are equal, logically the limit would be equal to +-inf, but that is 1/0 and is actually complex infinity in the sence that it does not make sense to say what direction in the complex plane is it in. In differential geometry, the complex plane is mapped onto the Riemann sphere and infinity is a single point on top of the sphere.

Comment: In any case a sequence can be made to yield any limit outside the open interval (-1,1).

Comment: "does every non converging limit diverge" I think so, however it can diverge in different ways.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34026/discussion-between-shubhankar-mondal-and-kiran-linsuain).

Comment: It can diverge to infinity or by oscillation.